# How can I add a Marker in google map?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to add one Marker in Google map. I successfully loaded map in my app but when I tried to add a Marker, the app got crashed. I don't know why. Please some one help me!

**My code:**

```
public class BasicMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.basic_demo);
        setUpMap();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }    

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

**Layout.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post you logcat then.

Comment: And where you obtain the map from the `SupportMapFragment`?

Comment: also post your layout.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method `setUpMapIfNeeded()` and called on `onResume()` and `onCreate()`

```
 private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
```

First you need to obtain the map from the `SupportMapFragment` and then you add `Marker` into map using

```
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Your_lat, Your_long)).title("Marker"));
```

Comment: @SP it's working now.thank u.i forget to get map from `SupportMapFragment`. you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  private void setUpMap() {
     Marker pos_Marker =  googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(starting).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_laumcher)).title("Starting Location").draggable(false));

            pos_Marker.showInfoWindow();
}
```